# trigger different events to autocomplete select and keyup enter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i'm using jquery ui autocomplete in an input field. i'm using the select event to trigger some actions, but this also triggers the keyup event if the user selects something using enter.

what i want to do:

```
$( '.my-input' ).autocomplete( {
    source: availableTags,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log( 'here goes an action triggered by the selection of an autocomplete suggestion' );
    }
});
$( '.my-input' ).keyup( function( e ) {
    if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {
        console.log( 'here goes an action triggered by the enter key' );
    }
});
```

using this code, the action supposed to be triggered by the enter key is being triggered when i select an autocomplete suggestion using enter. how can i avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the event on select value:

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags,
select: function(event, ui){
    var key = checkEvent(event);
    if (key == 13)
        alert('Enter key...');
    else 
        alert('other key pressed.');
}
});

function checkEvent(e) {
    if (window.event)
      key = window.event.keyCode;     //IE
    else
      key = e.which;     //firefox

return key;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but actually i need the opposite: check inside the keyup event if it was a simple enter pressed in the input or an enter pressed to select something.